# Mongoose removes whole document instead of removing element from nested array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have this structure :

```
{
    name : 'name1'
    projects : [
      {projectId : 123 , ...more},
      {projectId : 124 , ...more},
      {projectId : 125 , ...more},
    ]
  }
  
  {
    name : 'name2'
    projects : [
      {projectId : 126 , ...}
      {projectId : 127 , ...}
    ]
  }
```

To find a single entry based on projectId , I am using the following code :

```
   const project = await ClientManager.findOne({
  project: {$elemMatch: { projectId: projectId } },
}, {'project.$': 1});
```

This works. But now I want to remove a single project from the projects array instead of just finding the document.

I tried adding remove at the end but this deletes my whole document. I just want to remove the single project that matches the given projectId from the projects array:

```
const project = await ClientManager.findOne(
  {
    project: { $elemMatch: { projectId: projectId } },
  },
  { 'project.$': 1 }
).remove();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove a single item from the projects array you can use $pull

```
await ClientManager.findOneAndUpdate(
  { "projects.projectId": projectId },
  { $pull: { projects: {projectId: projectId} } }
);
```

Also, you don't need to use $elemMatch to find the document as you are just checking for a single field i.e. projectId. You can do this query instead

```
const project = await ClientManager.findOne({
  "projects.projectId": projectId
}, {"project.$": 1});
```

Comment: Your solution removes the entire collection including name etc

Comment: I think you want to just remove item from that projects array not the document?

Comment: Let me edit my answer and question as well because you mentioned that it's removing the entire collection which is not correct